# push group result into array mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this query in mongodb:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $group: { 
            _id: "$type",
//             items: { $push: "$_id.type" }
//             items: { $addToSet: "$_id.type" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {  
            _id: 0,
            type: "$_id",
        }
    }
]).toArray()
```

This will return a list like this:
`[ {type: "AAA"}, {type: "BBB"}, {type: "CCC"} ]`

But can I get something like this: `["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]`? Tried with `$push` and `$addToSet` but no result. Thank you for your time!

Later edit:
You can find an example here:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/-n0o5i6CnLq

Comment: you can group by null, like this `_id: null` instead of `_id: "$type"`

Comment: Can you please provide some sample documents?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I added a link. And the result I want to obtain is `["Male", "Female", "Rather not say", "Other"]`, an array, not an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Like this?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jJNATj3vRhc)

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      type: {
        $push: "$type"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      type: 1
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      type: {
        "$addToSet": "$type"
      }
    }
  }
])
```